# Why does a a Cypress test fail when rerunning after the first time

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I am using Cypress to test an Angular application. I am using firefox as the browser option.

I have opened the Cypress GUI and Click on the test to start it. For example here I click on 'overview-ibc-list.spec.js'

[image]

The test runs successfully.

After that, I want to run the test again, so click the restart button. Or for example, I make changes in the code that are detected which restarts the test.

This time around though, the test fails because the original route I declared in cy.visit("http://localhost:4200/#/history/ibc/574015") is rerouted to the base URL ('http://localhost:4200/').

Shouldn't the test conditions not be the exact same the second time around?

My original thought is it could be some caching issue or local storage but I used the *clearCookies* and *clearLocalStorage* commands in the **beforeEach** function.

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    if (canRestart) {
      cy.reload(true);
      cy.clearCookies();
      cy.clearLocalStorage();
      cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/#/history/ibc/574015');
      canRestart = false;
    }
  });
```

So my question is why is this happening and how can I make the test environment the exact same when restarting the test from the first time around?

Currently, to successfully repeat the tests I have to navigate back to the menu in the GUI and stop the test completely, then click back on the test to restart it. Not Ideal

thanks.

Comment: I have similar issue on a VUE app and it started when we were on version 5.5 and installed plugin `cypress-terminal-report` so I always connect the 2 things in my mind. May be you have some plugin like that

Comment: You can change the beforeEach() to a before() and ditch the canRestart variable. Logically it's the same thing, but maybe somehow canRestart does not get cleared in a hot module reload (you don't show how it is initialized).

Comment: Is it possible that the application is still compiling when the testing restarts? You could use the wait command in beforeEach to make sure that the application has restarted properly before restarting the testing.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your comment seems to have fixed the problem :)